# Illustrator: how to invert colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, svg, pen-tool

I'm making an SVG (image below) and I need to invert the colors (turn the outside stroke colors to the fill colors). How can i do it?

Second question: What is better for painting an SVG, the paintbrush or pen tool?
I prefer the paintbrush because it's smoother and can make rounded shapes with it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58157/how-do-i-use-the-paint-brush-with-a-fill-in-illustrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Invert (swap) the stroke and fill click this double arrow or hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> with the object selected:

[image]

I believe Pen and Brush will both be rendered equally in an SVG.

While the paintbrush offers freedom and a natural drawing feeling, the pen can make very predictable and precise curves.

Try clicking the pen tool on your artboard, click and hold on the other side of your artboard and drag the mouse around to see what you can do with the curve. Once you get it close you can adjust everything about the curve with the handles and moving the points.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm making an SVG and I need to invert the colors(turn the outside stroke colors to the fill colors)

[How do I use the paint brush with a fill in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58157/how-do-i-use-the-paint-brush-with-a-fill-in-illustrator)

> What is better for painting a SVG(I'm new to this) a paintbrush or a pen tool?

It depends.

As far as I'm aware there's no paintbrush vs pen tool debate. They are two completely different tools. Use the right tool for the right job.

But just so you know, the pen tool is fully capable of making rounded shapes, it is not restricted to making straight lines. I would learn to use both, but if I had to guess the pen tool is probably more popular of a tool overall.

Answer (score -1):

To swap the colors select the object and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.